# How can I get User mouse Position in Console using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, console, mouse

Is there any way to get user mouse coordinate in Console?

such as ...

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (mouse) => console.log(mouse.clientX, mouse.clientY));
```

yeah, it is possible to get coordinated in DOM! but is this possible to get mouse coordinate in the NodeJS console?

> *"* **I know That DOM and Node Js is Different** *"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use RobotJS to get the coordinates. Here's the example:

```js
var robot = require("robotjs");
robot.getMousePos();
// {x: 523, y: 127}
```